# Add another background to a div and move it together jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a site develop in php and jquery.
I want in a div attach dynamically a second background and slide down at the same time of the first background.
If a user click on a section in the menu I attach the new background at the top of the first background and after the two background slide down until the second background go in the old position of the old background. After the animation I remove the old background.
How can I make a similar thing? 
I don't know how to attach dynamically the new div and slide down at the same time the two background. How?

here is a simple code and after I develop the rest of the code.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5prn/)

html

```
<div></div>
```

css

```
html, body, div { height: 100%;}
div {
    opacity: .3; /*just to see there is no overlap*/
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background: url(http://www.dummyimage.com/643x12/001aff/ffffff.png&text=643+x+12) top left no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you want by giving some reference? It's hard to understand what you are wanting from what you're saying.

Comment: I want to attacch in a div a second background at the top of the first and with an animation in jquery slide down all the backgrounds of some px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5prn/6/)

***HTML***

```
<button> click </button>
<div></div>
```

***CSS***

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid;
    top:100px;
    left:0;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 120px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image:    
        url(http://www.dummyimage.com/400x120/00ff00/ffffff.png),
        url(http://www.dummyimage.com/400x120/00ff00/ffffff.png);
    background-position: 0 -120px, 0 0;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;

    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
       -moz-transition: all 1s;
         -o-transition: all 1s;
            transition: all 1s;
}

.hover {
    background-position: 0 0, 0 120px;
}
```

***jQuery***

```
var bgImg  = $("div").css("background-image"),
    bgImg2 = 'url(http://www.dummyimage.com/400x120/001aff/ffffff.png)';   

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("div")
        .css({ "backgroundImage" : bgImg2 + ", " + bgImg })
        .addClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: no I want a second background in the same div sorry, if I'd want a second div it was very easily, I can't do in this mode

Comment: you're aware that multiple backgrounds are available in the newer browsers only, right?

Comment: yes I know but is the only way to make this site I know isn't a good solution

Comment: I've updated the answer with multiple BG-s on the same element

Comment: ok great work for now.. but now is possible to add dynamically on document.ready the second background instead of insert it into the css?

Comment: yes, it is possible.. with a tiny hack - you have to put your original BG image in your CSS twice to make the multiple backgrounds work correctly - see updated answer

Comment: remember - *"you're aware that multiple backgrounds are available in the newer browsers only, right? "* :)

Comment: according to [**this**](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple) - yes.. but apparently it has some issues

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, I'm not really understanding all your wishes, but I can suggest you something. Use a bigger image with one strip as (whatever) red color and one as (whatever) blue. Use the `background-position` CSS property to change the position. You can slide the position by using the `.animate()` function of jquery.

This is just a suggestion, I would really want you to show us your progress with javascript, or some reference of what you want to replicate or anything.

CSS

```
div {
  background-position-y:-100px;
}
```

JS

```
$('div').animate({'background-position-y':'0'}, 1000);
```

This image should have 2 strips of height 100px each in different colors, and you will have to call the javascript from any action button.

Comment: ok but can you add a little bit of code to add dynamically to a div another background? for example? :)